# PCIe DMA problems in ARM Machines

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, dma, pci

I'm trying to write a PCIe driver for an ARM machine (Cavium ThunderX2). I'm working with Xilinx Alveo FPGAs. Our work involves migrating pages between heterogeneous nodes (x86 and ARM) and the driver takes care of the DMA between the host and the FPGA, and handles the device interrupts.

The DMA doesn't work (From Device/To Device) and I get "ARM SMMU v3.x 0x10 event occurred" errors. I tried disabling the SMMU (recommended by some threads in the NVIDIA community - https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-dma-works-in-arm-the-dma-stopped-working-with-our-pci-driver/53699), but that leads to a protection issue ("RAS Controller stopped"), and the system hangs.

I use dma_map_single APIs from dma-mapping.h to convert the virtual address to a DMA-capable bus address. Would dma_alloc_coherent make a difference? (Of course, I'll try this out)

I'm unable to figure out the problem. Is this is a PCIe driver issue or an issue with the device or is there a fix/patch available for ARM PCIe DMA ops? Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks,

Narayan

[Error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTkYi.png)

Comment: hmm. prprietary device, no code, vague error description (doesn't work). Does your hardware test code run?

Comment: Hello @stark

I have attached a snippet of the error. The code is very simple - dma_map_single(..params..). I'm trying to run my hardware test code, which doesn't work in ARM machines but it does in x86 machines.
Any ideas?